# Hide locale prefix with Next.JS sub-path internationalized i18n routing

Tags: next.js, localization, router

**Problem:**
I want to add two extra languages to a Next.JS website. The internationalized routing function with the automatic locale detection seems great. However, I don't want the forced prefixes as it creates a need for many separate, duplicated pages.

**Goal:**
I just need the locale, which I can then use to dynamically load the text that I need (from objects that are accompanied by their translations, which I pull from CMS). Like so:  `<p>{item.title[locale]}</p>`

Am I missing something? Some way to access the locale object within the Router, without activating the routing, would be a solution.

With forced prefixes, I would need to duplicate all my pages three times, bloating my project and adding a lot of work.

Hope someone can help!

Greets from the Netherlands.

Comment: you can access the current locale with `useRouter()`, but you don't have to duplicate any page, you only create one page and Next.js handle the locale automatically. You just have specify which locale to load when routing using `Link` or `router.push()`. Read more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing)